# JavaFx Custom Controls and Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, javafx, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add custom controls to the example I found here: https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/16/spring-tips-javafx
(code: https://github.com/ecovaci/javafx-spring-boot/tree/master)

My goal is of course to have the ability to autowire a business service in my controllers:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

I can do this via constructor injection in the non custom controls like this:

```
@Component
public class SimpleUiController {

    private final HostServices hostServices;

    @FXML
    public Label label;

    @FXML
    public Button button;

    private TestService testService;

    public SimpleUiController(HostServices hostServices, TestService testService) {
        Assert.notNull(testService);
        this.hostServices = hostServices;
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize () {
        this.button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> this.testService.test());
    }
}
```

What I would like next is to add a custom control in fxml with an accompanying controller.
So I quit naively copied the code snippets found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

```
<!-- custom_control.fxml -->
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
  <Button text="Click Me" />
</fx:root>
```

```
@Component
public class CustomControl extends VBox {
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    private TestService testService;

    public CustomControl(TestService testService) {
        Assert.notNull(testService);
        this.testService = testService;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/custom_control.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        textProperty().set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return textField.textProperty();
    }
}
```

Now I can use my custom control like this:

```
<!--ui.fxml-->
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="com.example.javafx.SimpleUiController">
      <Button fx:id="button" text="Button" />
      <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />

      <CustomControl text="100"/>
</VBox>
```

But when I add the custom control, I get the following exception.

```
Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.javafx.CustomControl.<init>()
```

I'm rather new to JavaFx and I was happy to find some articles about the integration with Spring. But I didn't find any reference about custom controls and spring. It almost feels like I'm the only one trying to achieve this, am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you include a custom control like this in an FXML file is that the `FXMLLoader` instantiates the control via reflection, calling (by default) the no-arg constructor. You would need to arrange for the `FXMLLoader` to retrieve the instance of the control from the spring application context. I think the way to do this would be to use a custom [builder factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setBuilderFactory(javafx.util.BuilderFactory)) on the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: I think the issue with the code in your (deleted) answer is returning null if the object is not obtainable from Spring. (So I suspect it's failing on the `Button` and `Label` in the FXML, not on the custom control. Create a `JavaFxBuilderFactory` in your custom builder factory, and return the result of `getBuilder()` from that if there's no qualifying bean.

Comment: I'm also running into the following error: Property "text" does not exist or is read-only. Since the builder I'm creating doesn't expose my getters and setters from my bean. Do you also have an elegant solution for that @James_D? ;o)

Comment: I think that's just a case of opening your package to `javafx.fxml` so that it can use reflection, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by adding a custom builder factory as suggested by James_D.

```
@Component
public class BeanBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
    try {
      Object bean = this.context.getBean(type);
      if (bean.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) {

        if (bean instanceof CustomControl) {
          return new CustomControlBuilder((CustomControl) bean);
        }
      }
      JavaFXBuilderFactory javaFXBuilderFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();
      return javaFXBuilderFactory.getBuilder(bean.getClass());
    } catch (BeansException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I had to create a builder for my custom component. I guess there are also opportunities to use reflection, but I didn't get that working.

```
public class CustomControlBuilder implements Builder<CustomControl> {

  private CustomControl customControl;

  public CustomControlBuilder(CustomControl customControl) {
    this.customControl = customControl;
  }

  public String getText() {
    return customControl.getText();
  }

  public void setText(String value) {
    customControl.setText(value);
  }

  @Override
  public CustomControl build() {
    return customControl;
  }
}
```

Here is the stageListener from the original example where I added the builder factory:

```
@Component
public class StageListener implements ApplicationListener<JavafxApplication.StageReadyEvent> {

    private final String applicationTitle;
    private final Resource fxml;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final BeanBuilderFactory beanBuilderFactory;

    public StageListener(@Value("${spring.application.ui.title}") String applicationTitle,
                         @Value("classpath:/ui.fxml") Resource fxml, ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                         BeanBuilderFactory aBeanBuilderFactory) {
        this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
        this.fxml = fxml;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.beanBuilderFactory = aBeanBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(JavafxApplication.StageReadyEvent stageReadyEvent) {
        try {
            Stage stage = stageReadyEvent.getStage();
            URL url = fxml.getURL();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
            fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(beanBuilderFactory);
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle(this.applicationTitle);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```